# How should I cache a page that supposed to keep track for every view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I've got a product page. The show action has the following code:

```
def show
  ...
  LiveView.add_live_view(@product, request)
  ...
end
```

In this same controller, if I have:

```
caches_action :show, :cache_path => (proc do 
  product_path(params[:id], :user_id => user_signed_in? ? current_user.id : nil)
end)
```

I'm trying to display real-time views, by grabbing the IP address from `request`. So, I need to keep track of every view that hits the page. However, if the page is already cached, it will never trigger the `LiveView.add_live_view(@product, request)` method.

The question is. Should I be caching this action? If so, how should it be done? Or should I forget about caching for this method?

Should I think of a different caching approach? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if caching at the application level is the right solution. I suggest looking at [mod_cache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cache.html) which caches the response at the apache layer. (If you are running apache with passenger).

Finally, don't forget about this rule. Never optimize unless you have to. What I mean is, test your application first. Doesn't suffer performance loss if you don't cache. Do you still need to cache everything? Do some code analysis and maybe you can use a better algorithm.

Edit, also look at HTTP status code [304](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html). If the user refreshes the page, and you can convey that nothing has changed then just return 304.

Comment: I like this rule. However, I've heard that it's best to always cache a `show` page. Which is beneficial if the same user decides to hit the reload button or visit the same page again. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I forgot to mention, that our app is running on Heroku. So don't think we have access below the application layer.

Comment: First I would check to see what is the affect of not caching anything. Also if you have web analytics, do check to see how many people actually refresh the page. Finally, if you do decide to cache this page, start by checking the timestamp and if nothing has changed then return 304 status. I honestly think this is what most developers forget to do. The browser's cache is exactly for this.

Comment: So basically client side caching through an ETag header? Will that still trigger the methods in the `show action` though?

Comment: No, the idea would be to check the timestamp and then do `render :nothing => true, :status => 304` followed by `return true`. This obviously has to be the first thing that the `show` action does.

Comment: @ChristianFazzini Let me point to something better. HttpCacheResponder (http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/responders/master/Responders/HttpCacheResponder) does basically this. However, you read it, it says it is often not used with HTML pages because so much changes. I am starting to take my own answer back and say perhaps you should just cache parts in rails.

Comment: Yea, I realize that other portions of the code need to be optimized. I can see this when caching is disabled. But that's not the issue. I'm trying to find out how to cache a page that is keeping track of `live views`